# Asymptotic time complexity of a two-loop program

Tags: time-complexity, imperative-programming, loops

I have two pieces of code in a function which I'm trying to calculate the asymptotic running time for:

```
for (int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
    total  +=  total;
    total  +=  x;
}
```

and:

```
while (y > 0) {
    total  -=  y;
    y  =  y/2;
}
```

Combining those two pieces of code, what is the run time of that function and how do I calculate it?

Comment: what do you mean combining? combining how? How is y initialized? Is this homework?

Comment: Do you want to measure the time or calculate a theoretical time ?

Comment: @PaulR tagged as Big-O, sounds like theoretical

Comment: combining as in they're in the same function

Answer (score 2):

The first loop has $y$ iterations, each iteration takes constant time ($O(1)$), so all together we have $O(y)$. The second loop has $\log_2(y)$ iterations of constant time, giving a complexity of $O(\log_2(y))$. Both loops together we have: $O(y + \log_2(y)) = O(y)$ because $y$ dominates $\log_2(y)$.

Comment: It looks to me like the first loop has y iterations, so it would be O(y), which is dominant over O(ld(y)), so the overall complexity would be O(y).

Comment: ^ Exactly. That is the proper big-o runtime

Comment: @Kevin you are right - I had overlooked the initialization `x=0` ...

Comment: @coproc what do you mean by ld(y)? I've never heard of ld() before, so could you please explain a bit further?

Comment: @Lost ld is the "logarithmus dualis", the logarithm with base two. In other words: z = ld(y) is equivalent to 2^z = y